# VMWare Workstation Pro 15.0 rolling back setup on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to install VMWare Workstation Pro 15.0 32-bit version on my 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1 machine but it always rolls back setup.

I tried rebooting, deleting vmkbd3 key from the registry, but always the same.
It even places icon on the desktop and than prompts a window with exclamation mark and button OK. When clicked it rolls back the installation process and says that setup has ended up prematurely. It's just so frustrating. I tried from cmd to repair installation file but interestingly I can't. It doesn't even want to repair the damn setup file. Finally, I tried removing cache it created in Program Files in Common Files folder but again the same damn thing happens.

Why the same 32-bit version wants to install and work on my 64-bit Windows 10 Professional from which I'm posting this thread right now, but fiercely refuses to install and work on 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate machine?

I even installed update KB3033929 which some people claimed that solves the issue. And the same thing happens all over again.

Does anybody have a clue how to get it up and running because I've read so many threads about the same issue and just nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really sorry that I wasn't looking for answers here, because before I received any answer here, I managed to do what I intended to do. The thing is, you can install VMWare Workstation 15.0 x86 version on Windows 7 64-bit, *BUT*, you can't do it on fresh installed version of the OS. I tried just with Service Pack 1. It didn't work. Then I installed KB2533552 update. I really can't tell if that would work with just that update, or with KB2999226 I also installed, but all previously mentioned updates together with KB3033929 worked perfectly for me so I managed to install and run application on the Windows 7.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Win 7 SP1, you'll need to get the 15.5 installer.

See:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2129859
This table lists the supported host operating systems for VMware Workstation Pro 12.x, 14.x,15.x and 15.5. VMware Workstation Pro 12.x and above only supports 64-bit host operating systems.

Note: VMware Workstation 15.x and above is compatible with Windows 10 1903 as a host operating system.

...specifically...

| OS Vendor | OS Release | Workstation 12.x | Workstation 14.x | Workstation 15.x | Workstation 15.5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Microsoft | Windows 7 SP1 |  |  |  | Yes |
| Microsoft | Windows 7 | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

EDIT:
I was able to successfully install Workstation 15.0.4 on a Win7 SP1 VM.  This is a fresh install w/o any Windows Updates for obvious reasons, so it's not super helpful in your case.
I'd definitely recommend upgrading to Windows 10 on your host as your best option and then trying the 15.5.x installer on your Win7SP1 system.
I was able to find both versions in my "My VMware" account, as I've purchased version 15 previously.